# SVG in Clojurescript

Tags: svg, clojurescript

What's the best way to add SVG elements to the dom in Clojurescript ? The Twitterbuzz example uses Google Closure lib's Graphics objects, but say I didn't care about IE compatibility, is there a way I could add elements the way html is `(dom/build [:svg [:g [:text "something like this ?"]]])`
I tried Closure's graphics lib but I don't get to use a lot of handy SVG features. I tried Apogee, but that serializes the SVG code and I would prefer direct DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dom/build constructs DOM elements without the namespace. You need to either enhance dom/build or write one for SVG. I use the following code to create SVG elements.

```
(defn element-ns
  "Create a namespaced dom element"
  [namespace tag & args]
  (let [[tag attrs children] (normalize-args tag args)
        parent (. js/document createElementNS namespace (name tag))
        [parent children] (if (string? (first children))
                            [(set-text (element-ns namespace tag attrs) (first children))
                             (rest children)]
                            [parent children])]
    (doseq [[k v] attrs]
      (. parent setAttributeNS nil (name k) v))
    (apply append parent children)))

(defn build-svg
  "Build up a svg element from nested vectors."
  [x]
  (if (vector? x)
    (let [[parent children] (if (keyword? (first x))
                          [(apply element-ns "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" (take-while element-arg? x))
                           (drop-while element-arg? x)]
                          [(first x) (rest x)])
       children (map build-svg children)]
       (apply append parent children))
    x))
```

Comment: Where are `element-arg?` `normalize-args`, `set-text`, and `append` defined?

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in my [cljs-d3](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljs-d3/) library, which is a ClojureScript wrapper for the D3 JavaScript library.
D3 is an excellent tool for manipulating an SVG DOM.

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) for SVG? This is what I plan to use for several real time projects.

Comment: because AFAIK, Enlive is a HTML templating lib which is good for generating HTML on the server, whereas I'm generating SVG on the client at runtime. Also I don't think it supports XML namespaces which I'd need for SVG

Comment: Ahh I see, my apologies - have a look at 'Enfocus' for ClojureScript land. I will be generating svg from both client and server as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load svg as an external asset try loading it as text and appending it to a div leveraging cljs-d3:

```
(defn load-svg-as-text []
 (fn []
   (let [on-complete (fn [error externalSVGText]
    (-> d3
     (.select "#viewport")
     (.html externalSVGText))
    )]
  (-> d3
    (.text "images/smartcity.svg" on-complete)))))
```

I got the idea from [AmeliaBR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128209/ameliabr) nice answer in this [js thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209549/embed-and-refer-to-an-external-svg-via-d3-and-or-javascript) and then ported it to ClojureScript