# How to access svg:image's elements when image is external and loaded in to a svg:g

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm loading circle.svg in to a svg's group and want to access circle's elements (minus or svgbar). Anything within the circle.svg comes up as null or undefined though.

I tried loading it as an object but it doesn't even load the image.
I tried searching through the contentDocument but contentDocument is undefined.

Any help will be appreciated.

circle.svg's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="minus" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px" >
<circle id="svgbar" cx="16" cy="16" r="16" />
<rect id="iline" x="8" y="14" fill="#F9F9F9" width="16" height="4" />
</svg>
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to access externally loaded svg elements</title>

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var vis = d3.select( "body" ).append( "svg" ).attr( "id", "svgObj" );
            var grp = vis.append( "g" ).attr( "id", "grp" );

            /*var img = grp.append( "object" )
                    .attr( "type", "image/svg+xml" )
                    .attr( "data", "imgs/nav/circle.svg" );*/

            var img = grp.append( "image" )
                    .attr( "id", "collapse" )
                    .attr( "xlink:href", "imgs/nav/circle.svg" );

                    img.attr( "height", 20 )
                    .attr( "width", 20 )
                    .on( "mouseover", function() {

                        console.log( "overing..." );
                    } );


            var befSvgObj = document.getElementById('svgObj');
            console.log( "befSvgObj: " + befSvgObj );

            // wait until all the resources are loaded
            window.addEventListener( "load", findSVGElements, false);           

            function findSVGElements()  {

                var contDoc = befSvgObj.contentDocument;

                var svgObj = document.getElementById('svgObj');
                var gObj = document.getElementById( 'grp' );
                var cObj = document.getElementById( 'collapse' );
                            var svgBar = document.getElementById( 'svgBar' );
                var minus = document.getElementById('minus'); // null
                //var minus2 = cObj.contentDocument.getElementById( 'minus' );
                 // Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

                console.log( "svgObj: " + svgObj );
                console.log( "gObj: " + gObj );
                console.log( "cObj: " + cObj );
                console.log( "minus: " + minus );

                console.log( "svgObj.contentDocument: " + svgObj.contentDocument );
                console.log( "gObj.contentDocument: " + gObj.contentDocument );
                console.log( "cObj.contentDocument: " + cObj.contentDocument );
                console.log( "contDoc: " + contDoc );
                            console.log( "svgBar: " + svgBar );

            }


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you embed an external SVG as an image, that's all you get -- the image, you cannot modify it anymore than you could a PNG or JPEG image.  [Read the W3 specs for more.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement)

If you need to access or modify the content of the external SVG, [this answer describes how to read the external file as XML and insert it in your current document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289967/3128209).

Comment: Thanks, I can see it in my Elements debug now but still not able to access the svg elements using document.getElementById nor contentDocument.getElementById

Comment: Are you still calling your `findSVGElements` method in a window load event?  Because you have to wait until *after* `d3.xml` has triggered its asynchronous callback method.  That's the only reason I can think why `document.getElementById()` would fail.  (Well, that or a conflict between `id` values between the inserted content and the rest of the document -- but you seem to have unique values in your example.)  `contentDocument` will fail because this isn't an embedded object, there is no content document: see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Scripting)

Comment: Thanks! That was part of it. I'm able to retrieve the svg element now "minus", but still not its content "svgbar".
See the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IneBoGOt/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: The bin doesn't work because of cross-origin access errors, but I'm pretty sure the problem's a simple typo: "svgBar" vs "svgbar".

Comment: You are awesome! I'm so embarrassed :)