# Can I display a dot or xdot layout file generated by GraphViz using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, graphviz, dot

I have created a web service which generates dot and xdot layout files for a graph using GraphViz on a server. Is there a way to visualise either dot or xdot files with d3.js on the clients browser?

If not, are there other JavaScript libraries which can visualise dot or xdot layouts?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24736418/274350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GraphViz documentation [says](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf):

> ## 1 Basic Graph Drawing
>
> *dot* draws directed graphs. It reads attributed graph text ﬁles and writes drawings,
>   either as graph ﬁles or in a graphics format such as GIF, PNG, SVG, PDF, or
>   PostScript.

If you can get your graph output as SVG, you can manipulate it with d3.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289967/3128209) describes how to read an external SVG file as XML and insert it into your document.

Comment: By the way, if all you want to do is *display* the visualization, and not manipulate it or interact with it, it might be easiest to have your server convert it to PNG and just display it as an image.

Answer (score 2):

Soooooo late to the party, but now you can do this with [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://viz-js.com/bower_components/viz.js/viz-lite.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.1.2/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');
</script>
```

Also check out this [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/magjac/4acffdb3afbc4f71b448a210b5060bca)

Answer (score 2):

There were several solutions around, but none of them did what I really wanted: **take some nice, working `D3js` graph visualisation code and feed it with `.dot` file instead of `.json` file.**

That's why I created an adapter which will basically allow you to use `.dot` files with any of thousands of `D3js` samples by changing just one statement. If you have some `D3js` visualisation working on following data-structure:

```
{
  "nodes": [ {"id": "Myriel"}, {"id": "Napoleon"}],
  "links": [ {"source": "Myriel"}, {"target": "Napoleon"}]
}
```

Just include following script and call `d3.dot`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gmamaladze/d3-dot-graph@1.0.0/build/d3-dot-graph.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.dot(url, function(graph) {
   ...
});

</script>
```

instead of:

```
d3.json(url, function(graph) {...});
```

[GitHub repository with code and examples](https://github.com/gmamaladze/d3-dot-graph)