# Reading DOT files in javascript/d3

Tags: d3.js, dot

Is there a standard way to read and parse DOT graph files in javascript, ideally in way that will work nicely in d3?

Currently, the only thing I can think of doing is reading plain text and doing my own parsing. Hopefully this'd be reinventing the wheel though.

```
d3.text("graph.dot", function(error, dotGraph) {
    ....
)};
```

Comment: Have you seen [graphlib-dot](https://github.com/cpettitt/graphlib-dot)?

Comment: Yeah, but haven't been able to get it to work..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

⚠ Solution proposed here depends on two libraries marked as unsupported by their authors.

To get Graphviz DOT files rendered in Javascript, combine the [graphlib-dot](https://github.com/cpettitt/graphlib-dot) and [dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3) libraries.

The `graphlibDot.read()` method takes a graph or digraph definition in DOT syntax and produces a graph object.  The `dagreD3.render()` method can then output this graph object to SVG.

You can then use additional D3 methods to add functionality to the graph, retrieving additional node and edge attributes from the graphlib graph object as needed.

A trivial self-contained example is:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Parse the DOT syntax into a graphlib object.
  var g = graphlibDot.read(
    'digraph {\n' +
    '    a -> b;\n' +
    '    }'
  )

  // Render the graphlib object using d3.
  var render = new dagreD3.render();
  render(d3.select("svg g"), g);


  // Optional - resize the SVG element based on the contents.
  var svg = document.querySelector('#graphContainer');
  var bbox = svg.getBBox();
  svg.style.width = bbox.width + 40.0 + "px";
  svg.style.height = bbox.height + 40.0 + "px";
}
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.node rect {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: #fff;
}
.edgeLabel rect {
  fill: #fff;
}
.edgePath {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dagrejs.github.io/project/graphlib-dot/v0.6.4/graphlib-dot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/v0.5.0/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  </script>
  <svg id="graphContainer">
    <g/>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks great! I'm having a problem with your example though.. my graph is larger than my screen, and there are no scrollbars to pan around.. is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: You need to set the width and height of your SVG element.  I haven't found a really good way of setting these automatically from the graph content, so I currently set them to really large values, or use trial and error.

Comment: My graphs are generated dynamically, so it would definitely be nice to figure them out from content.. I'll let you know if I figure something out!

Comment: I've got something working in Firefox and Chrome, but haven't tested it extensively.  After rendering the graph, call getBBox() on your SVG element to get the bounding box of the contents, then set the style.width and style.height attributes based on the bounding box plus any padding.  I will update the example to reflect this.

Comment: Great! How do you change `var g` to read from a file?  is it something lie: `fs.readFileSync('graph.dot', 'UTF-8')`?

Comment: @sAguinaga that's a different question.  I suggest you try a few things, see what problems you run into, search for solutions and ask another question if you don't find an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party, but if you're still interested, here's a way to do it with the new [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) plug-in that I just released:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://viz-js.com/bower_components/viz.js/viz-lite.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.0.4/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this snippet @magjac (and for the d3-graphgiz plugin)! I think there's a missing `https` in front of `//d3js.org` in the first `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. However, now I'm getting an error for https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.0.4/d3-graphviz.min.js which I don't understand.

Comment: .@magjac hm, not having the same issue on my end ... maybe something to do with certificates on your machine since the url is using https?

Comment: beside the fact the example is not running but i tested it's the best solution it preserves the formatting of graph

Comment: @magjac will your library also read json?

Comment: @joshlsullivan No, it can only read DOT source files.

Answer (score 4):

Same example, using latest version of graphlib-dot and dagre-d3.

```js
window.onload = function() {
      // Parse the DOT syntax into a graphlib object.
      var g = graphlibDot.read(
        'digraph {\n' +
        '    a -> b;\n' +
        '    }'
      )

      // Render the graphlib object using d3.
      var renderer = dagreD3.render();
      d3.select("svg g").call(renderer, g);


      // Optional - resize the SVG element based on the contents.
      var svg = document.querySelector('#graphContainer');
      var bbox = svg.getBBox();
      svg.style.width = bbox.width + 40.0 + "px";
      svg.style.height = bbox.height + 40.0 + "px";
    }
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.node rect {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: #fff;
}
.edgeLabel rect {
  fill: #fff;
}
.edgePath {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/graphlib-dot/latest/graphlib-dot.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.js"></script>

    <html>

    <body>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      </script>
      <svg id="graphContainer">
        <g/>
      </svg>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: This updated code works, but the svg rendering of the DOT file output is very dependent on the parse order of the Nodes and Edges.  The older versions seemed to render the DOT file without issue.

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for a possibility to visualise `.dot` files einther in `javascript` or `D3js`. I think the solution from the highest rated answer will work for most of you.

I was unhappy because of these 3 reasons:

1. It involves libraries like `lowdash`, `dagre` and `graphlib` additionally to `D3js` and is heavyweight.
2. Parser output is not a `D3js` "friedly" data-structure.
3. Usage (API) in not D3js style.

That's why I created an adapter which will basically allow you to use `.dot` files with any of thousands of `D3js` samples by changing just one statement. If you have some `D3js` visualisation working on following data-structure:

```
{
  "nodes": [ {"id": "Myriel"}, {"id": "Napoleon"}],
  "links": [ {"source": "Myriel"}, {"target": "Napoleon"}]
}
```

Just include following script and call `d3.dot`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gmamaladze/d3-dot-graph@1.0.0/build/d3-dot-graph.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.dot(url, function(graph) {
   ...
});

</script>
```

instead of:

```
d3.json(url, function(graph) {...});
```

[GitHub repository with code and examples](https://github.com/gmamaladze/d3-dot-graph)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm amazed that there's 2.5k lines of code in this. Brilliant stuff - I'm going to give it a try and talk about it to others if it works because many of the other routes I have tried, as you say, involve zillions of dependencies. This deserves wider 'visibility' ;-)