# add color to node dagre d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, dagre-d3, phpgraphlib

I have created a tree structure following the link
[Reading DOT files in javascript/d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595493/reading-dot-files-in-javascript-d3)

I need to fill the nodes with color.

**Tree data:**

[image]

I tried adding

```
[label="abcd" labelStyle="font: 300 14px" style=filled fillcolor=red]
[label="abcd" style=filled color=red]
```

Could anyone please suggest or point me in right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In you CSS section add this

```
.node rect {
            stroke: #333;
            fill: #ff0000;
        }
```

This will make your node color red.

Comment: Let's say that you wanted different colors for different nodes. Is dagre-d3 able to honor attributes set in the original DOT source?