# How to add to <SVG> element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, svg

I have an array with `<SVG>` element code. How can I append to that using JavaScript. I tried the following:

Example Array:

```
global_array[0] = [ '<svg data="BusinessProductFigure" x="553.671875"
y="167" id= "something" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
version="1.1"><rect x="4" y="4" width="60" height="14" 
fill="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-width="1"/></svg>' ]
```

Appending `[1]`

```
for(var i = 0; i <= global_array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("main_svg").innerHTML = global_array[i];
}
})
```

Gives no error but nothing is appended. Checked in console.

Appending test `[2]`

```
for(var i = 0; i <= global_array.length; i++) {
    d3.select("#main_svg").append(global_array[i]);
}
})
```

This gives DOM Exception error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 append (insert) existing SVG string (or element) to a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855452/d3-append-insert-existing-svg-string-or-element-to-a-div)

Comment: Your example array is assigning a sub-array to element zero of `global_array`.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach will almost work if you change the loop end condition from `i<=global_array.length` to `i<global_array.length`. I say *almost* because it will work only for the last element in the array. Setting `innerHTML` doesn't append an element - it replaces all content. Another requirement is that the container ("#main_svg") cannot be an `<svg>` tag. You cannot nest `<svg>`s

*Almost* working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/wd3w2rjL/

Answer (score 1):

here I could see in the first line..

change `global_array[0]` to `global_array`

**or**

```js
global_array[0] = '<svg data="BusinessProductFigure" x="553.671875"
 y="167" id= "something" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 version="1.1"><rect x="4" y="4" width="60" height="14" 
 fill="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-linejoin="round" 
 stroke="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-width="1"/></svg>';
```

this will work as per your code :)