# How to append an svg to an prexisting svg using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js, svg

is it possible to append another svg to a preexisting svg parent using d3.js?

I know that its possible by using an 'svg:image'-attribute.
But unfortunately then i am loosing full control about the inner svg-child.

*The regarding dom node gets created by d3 but is not rendered and as a result the page stays blank.*

Hope somebody can help, thx in advance :)

Here's what I got:

**Html CSS**

```html
  #svg-main-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  
  <div id="svg-main-wrapper">
    <div svg-container svg-src="svgContainer[0].url" position="svgContainer[0].position">
    </div>    
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```html
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .directive('svgContainer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: function() {
        var parent = angular.element('body');
        return '<svg class="svg-container" width="' + parent.width() + '" height="' + parent.height() + '" viewBox=" 0 0 ' + parent.width() + ' ' + parent.height() + '"preserveAspectRatio ="xMinYMax meet"></svg>';
      },
      scope: {
        svgSrc: '=',
        position: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var parent = angular.element('#svg-main-wrapper');

        var x = 0;
        var y = parent.height() - 400;

        var svg = d3.select(element[0]);
        var g = svg.append('g');

        var innersvg = g.append('svg')
          .attr('xlink:href', scope.svgSrc)
          .attr('preserveAspectRatio', scope.position)
          .attr('width', parent.width())
          .attr('height', 400)
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')');

      },
      replace: true
    };
  })

  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.svgContainer = [
      {
        id: 0,
        short_name: 'left',
        url: './images/complete.svg',
        position: 'none'
      }
      ];
  }]);
```

Comment: When you refer to the "svg:image" attribute, did you try using an `image` element -- `g.append('image')`? What was wrong with that approach?

Comment: The inner SVG element will be another complex SVG graphic. If it's just an image tag, iam not able to further manipulate it's child nodes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is: *"is it possible to append an SVG to an SVG using D3?"* That *object* in the title is a bit misleading (However, if you're really talking about an [`<object>`](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#object) or even loading an external SVG, you're doing it wrong, and the following explanation would be useless. In that case, answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289967/5768908) will be more useful).

The answer is yes. For whatever reason you want to nest those SVGs (you probably don't need it), just use the `append` method as you would with any other element.

Here is a demo, have a look at the console: there is an SVG inside an SVG.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.append("text")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .text("this text is in the outer SVG");
var innerSVG = svg.append("svg");
innerSVG.append("text")
  .attr("y", 50)
  .text("this text is in the inner SVG");

var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you going to draw that inner SVG or do you want to import it already made? In that last case, check the link in my answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the above code works. I want to append input checkbox. How to do that ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Arunjai It's not clear what you want. Please post this as a new question, with all relevant details.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, Like the above code appends text right like that I want to append checkbox. how to do that. if this is not clear I will post a new question.

Comment: @Arunjai It's very different. Besides that, I cannot answer a question in the comments section, so please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, our component will be code-driven, with nothing in the template except a div, which will serve as our container. The chart size will be inferred from the size of this element, which will be helpful in making the SVG react like a normal html node. Here is the main part of the code, the ‘src/app/bar-chart/bar-chart.component.ts’ file:

```
 private createChart(): void {
    d3.select('svg').remove();
    const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    const data = this.data;
    const svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
        .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
        .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);
    const contentWidth = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    const contentHeight = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    const x = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, contentWidth])
      .padding(0.1)
      .domain(data.map(d => d.letter));
    const y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([contentHeight, 0])
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.frequency)]);
    const g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');
    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + contentHeight + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, '%'))
      .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '0.71em')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text('Frequency');
    g.selectAll('.bar')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', d => x(d.letter))
        .attr('y', d => y(d.frequency))
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => contentHeight - y(d.frequency));
  }
}
```

Link webs: https://tienanhvn.blogspot.com/2019/06/create-responsive-angular-d3-charts.html